# issue with tinker and laravel

Tags: laravel, tinker

im trying to insert records in my database using tinker but i have an error : 
**Php warning : a non-numeric value encountered and no records are save.**

My factory :

```
$factory->define(App\Donne::class, function (Faker\Generator $faker) {
return [

    'nom_destinataire' => $faker->firstName($gender = null|'male'|'female'),
    'adresse_destinataire' => $faker->address,                                             
    'code_postal' => $faker->postcode,
    'localite_destinataire' => $faker->country,
    'port'=>$faker->randomLetter,
];
```

My tinker command

```
factory(App\Donne::class, 1)->create();
```

Thanks for help

Comment: Does your factory works within the code? It is not a tinker problem I believe, your usage does not seem right to me.. What is this `$faker->firstName($gender = null|'male'|'female')`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The examples in the package readme [here](https://github.com/fzaninotto/Faker#fakerprovideren_usperson) are for demonstrating the available options that can be passed to a function

#### Faker\Provider\en_US\Person

```
title($gender = null|'male'|'female')     // 'Ms.'
titleMale                                 // 'Mr.'
titleFemale                               // 'Ms.'
suffix                                    // 'Jr.'
name($gender = null|'male'|'female')      // 'Dr. Zane Stroman'
firstName($gender = null|'male'|'female') // 'Maynard'
firstNameMale                             // 'Maynard'
firstNameFemale                           // 'Rachel'
lastName                                  // 'Zulauf'
```

> DO NOT COPY PASTE, `|` means (either...or) in plain English

`firstName` function only accepts one optional argument, remove it if you want generated data to be either male or female randomly

```php
$factory->define(App\Donne::class, function (Faker\Generator $faker) {
    return [
        'nom_destinataire' => $faker->firstName(),
        'adresse_destinataire' => $faker->address,
        'code_postal' => $faker->postcode,
        'localite_destinataire' => $faker->country,
        'port' => $faker->randomLetter,
    ];
});
```

Hope this helps